# Нужно добавить гиперссылку и данные из api для телеграм бота на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, api, telebot, python-3.8

При написании телеграм бота потребовалось, чтобы при отправки сообщения он отправлял котировку криптовалюты и давал на нее ссылку, как сделать гиперссылку я понял, а как отправлять котировки нет. Помогите пожалуйста
Вот пример функции:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def bot_message(message):
        if message.chat.type == 'private':
            if message.text == 'BTC':
                req = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCUSDT")
                response = req.json()
                bidprice = response["bidPrice"]
                bot.send_message(
                    message.chat.id,
                    'Покупка [Bitcoin (BTC)](https://www.binance.com/ru/trade/BTCUSDT?layout=pro)',parse_mode = 'Markdown'
                    )
```

Нужно чтобы бот отправлял данные из json и гиперссылку на биржу. (Использовал библиотеку telebot)

Answer (score 0):

Эмм так просто напишите её в текст сообщения и всё.

```
bot.send_message(
    message.chat.id, 
    f'Покупка [Bitcoin (BTC)](https://www.binance.com/ru/trade/BTCUSDT?layout=pro) цена: {response["bidPrice"]}', parse_mode = 'Markdown'
)
```